# add array object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

May be it is dumb question.
I have array object like

```
var projects = [
        {
            value: "jquery",
            label: "jQuery",
            desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
            icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            value: "jquery-ui",
            label: "jQuery UI",
            desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
            icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            value: "sizzlejs",
            label: "Sizzle JS",
            desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
            icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
        }
    ];
```

length of 3

I want to add id in all objects like

```
        {
            id:1
            value: "jquery",
            label: "jQuery",
            desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
            icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            id:2
            value: "jquery-ui",
            label: "jQuery UI",
            desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
            icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            id:3
            value: "sizzlejs",
            label: "Sizzle JS",
            desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
            icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
        }
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

```
projects = projects.map(function(itm,i){
 return (itm.id = i+1, itm);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0h3pg1ya/1/)

If you don't want to use functional programming, then you can use a simple for loop for this purpose no need for "`forEach`",

```
for(var i=0,len=projects.length; i<len; i++){
  projects[i].id = i+1;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit odd cloning the array for no reason, in a way that mutates the original objects anyway.

Comment: @Emissary Let OP know about that(`map`) also. It would be handy for him in other occasions. Also I have provided a solution for the problem that you are saying by a simple for loop.

Answer (score 2):

No need for Array#map, because the access is direct possible with `itm` as object.

```
projects.forEach(function(itm, i) {
   itm.id = i + 1;
});
```

Comment: but `forEach` method doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

If care about speed ) ... *"fast"* solution with "negative" `while` loop:

```
var len = projects.length;
while (len--) {
    projects[len]['id'] = len + 1;
}
```